# MS Access - on lost focus calculation

Tags: ms-access, minute

I am working on MS Access database and creating a form in access.

I have a field total_hrs. here I need help.

I want to just fill minutes and it should be converted into hrs.

for that I am using onlost focus total_hrs

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ABS(imin/60)` to calculate the hours, where imin is int.

```
sub Calc

Dim iHrs as int
dim iMin as int

iHrs = ABS(iMin/60)

End sub
```

you can put this code after onlost fouce even or after even

without looking at form or code it hard to help.